# Middleman i18n not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-i18n, middleman

I'm newbie using ruby and middleman, I've created my project and all are working fine, but when I go to `/es` path I don't get any translation. I've searched for info without any results and tried to move code between folders testing configs and nothing.

My folder structure is:

```
|locales
  |---en.yml
  |---es.yml
|source
  |es
    |---index.html.haml
  |layouts
    |---layout.html.haml
  |partials
    |_header.html.haml
    |_navigation.html.haml
  |---index.html.haml
```

My YAML files

**en.yml**

```
en:
  home: 'Home'
```

**es.yml**

```
es:
  home: 'Inicio'
```

My HAML

```
%nav
   = link_to t(:home), '/', class: "#{'active' if current_page.url == '/'}"
   = link_to 'Portfolio', '/portfolio', class: "#{'active' if current_page.url == '/portfolio/'}"
   = link_to t(:skills), '/skills', class: "#{'active' if current_page.url == '/skills/'}"
   = link_to t(:about), '/about', class: "#{'active' if current_page.url == '/about/'}"
   = link_to t(:contact), '/contact', class: "#{'active' if current_page.url == '/contact/'}"
```

My config

**config.rb**

```
###
# Page options, layouts, aliases and proxies
###

# Per-page layout changes:
#
# With no layout
page '/*.xml', layout: false
page '/*.json', layout: false
page '/*.txt', layout: false

# With alternative layout
# page "/path/to/file.html", layout: :otherlayout

# Proxy pages (http://middlemanapp.com/basics/dynamic-pages/)
# proxy "/this-page-has-no-template.html", "/template-file.html", locals: {
#  which_fake_page: "Rendering a fake page with a local variable" }

# General configuration
set :partials_dir, 'partials'
activate :i18n, :templates_dir => 'partials'
activate :directory_indexes

# Reload the browser automatically whenever files change
configure :development do
  activate :livereload
end

###
# Helpers
###

# Methods defined in the helpers block are available in templates
# helpers do
#   def some_helper
#     "Helping"
#   end
# end

# Build-specific configuration
configure :build do
  # Minify CSS on build
  activate :minify_css

  # Minify Javascript on build
  activate :minify_javascript
end
```

Comment: Do you mind sharing your code?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't write a comment, but I think this might be the reason, your es.yml is wrong, since it starts en:

```
 en:
    home: 'Inicio'
```

Shouldn't it be

```
 es:
    home: 'Inicio'
```

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake when I put my code. On `es.yml` the deault is `es:`

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is months old but I just had the same problem, looked all over the web for hours trying to find and answer and managed to fix the issue by adding these parameters after activating **i18n**:

**config.rb**

```
configure :build do
   activate :i18n,
      :mount_at_root => 'en',
      :lang_map => { :'en' => 'en', :'es' => 'es' },
      :path => '/'
end
```

Obviously, if you want **"es"** to be your default, change *mount_at_root*.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer! This issues it's still active on my old project. I will check it! ;)

Answer (score 0):

I achieved localized paths with separate URLs for English and Spanish by

adding **index.es.html.erb** in the root of the source directory

and setting **activate :i18n, :path => "/:locale/"** in the config.rb

In the browser, my language selector sends users to **/** or **/es**:

English

```
http://website.com/
```

Spanish

```
http://website.com/es
```

**Folder structure**

```
|data
  |---home.json
|locales
  |---en.yml
  |---es.yml
|source
  |---index.html.erb
  |---index.es.html.erb
  |---_slide.erb
|---config.rb
```

**config.rb**

```
configure :build do
  activate :i18n, :path => "/:locale/"
  activate :directory_indexes
  ...
end
```

**slide.erb**

Using **t** as a shortcut for **I18n.t**, I dynamically reference the translated value through the data.

```
<%= link_to t([data.link.text]),
    data.link.href,
    :id => data.link.id,
    :class => 'btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-dark'
%>
```

**home.json**

The value of "**text**" correlates to the key in the .yml files.

```
{
  "slides": [
    {
      "text": "slides.learnMore",
      ...
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

**en.yml**

```
en:
  slides:
    learnMore: "LEARN MORE"
    ...
```

**es.yml**

```
es:
  slides:
    learnMore: "APRENDE MÁS"
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Move all your `.erb.html` that require to be duplicated per language to the folder: `/source/localizable` as explained in the docs:

- https://middlemanapp.com/advanced/localization/#localizable-templates

You can change this folder name using the modifier: `templates_dir`:

```
# Look in `source/language_specific` instead
activate :i18n, :templates_dir => "language_specific"
```